# laravel proper url in mail blade template

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to put a link to my web app in my blade mail template, however the url is showing like this : http://127.0.0.1:8000/.$code->discount->url. instead of a properly built, valid url.

This is how I'm doing it:

```
<a href="{{ url('.$code->discount->url.') }}">Enlace</a>
```

I also tried with:

```
<a href="{{ $code->discount->url }}">Enlace</a>
```

Second way only gave me a partial url (see bellow), not the full url host and path).

$code->discount->url is /promociones/hamburguesa-de-queso

Comment: What you are getting for using `{{ url("/promociones/hamburguesa-de-queso") }}` ?

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the `'. .'` from around the `$code->discount->url`:

```
<a href="{{ url($code->discount->url) }}">Enlace</a>
```

The `url()` helper is PHP function so wrapping the `$code->discount->url` in quotes will cause php to see it as a literal string.